# Image not showing on product page and aslo admin in magento?

Tags: magento2, product, media

> I want to show my image on product page but its  display nothing please check image error below
> [image]

[image]

Comment: It clearly states the image is not in that directory. Some issue with the link building for img tag.

Comment: @AbdulSamadAbbasi Image is same directory but i am getting this type error

Comment: You haven't added any image for this product from admin?

Comment: I have added a product image   but its showing blank in  admin

Comment: I have added a product image please check above

Comment: are you using cloudfare cache?

Comment: @GohilRajesh No

Comment: @GohilRajesh Pleas check above image and help me

Comment: image available on path?

Comment: @GohilRajesh yes

Comment: @GohilRajesh why i am getting this i dont have idea help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you check the webserver config

- .htaccess
- nginx.conf

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html

Also, don't forget to check the rewrite URL in stores > configuration > general > web

Comment: I have solved it from  stores > configuration > general > web

Answer (score 0):

run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I have try this commands  but getting same issu

Answer (score 0):

Please try below command. it can take time depend on your products/images.

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```